# Validate filter when empty value or some other condition is met

Tags: zend-framework2

Im using this input filter on Zend2:

```
    $this->get('foo')->getValidatorChain()->attach(
        new GreaterThan(array(
            'min' => 1,
            'inclusive' => true
        ))
    );
```

This is working, but know I need to allow also that *foo* var to be empty, so if empty, it validates, if not empty it applies the *GreaterThan* condition to the value.

I tried to solve this just be adding: `$this->get('foo')->setAllowEmpty(true);` on top of that code, but is not working, it continuous to validates the *GreaterThan* condition.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Could you state what class `$this` is along with what it is extending?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would attach the validator after the post and before the validate within the controller. You could also add a method to your form class but for demonstration purposes I try to keep this short and simple but it prob be cleaner doing this within the form.

```
...
if($request->isPost()) {
   $data = $request->getpost();
   if(!empty($data['foo'])) {
     $form->get('foo')->getValidatorChain()->attach(
        new GreaterThan(array(
        'min' => 1,
        'inclusive' => true ))
     );
   }
   if($form->isValid()) {
      //your code
   }
}
...
```

There also is the possibility to create your own validator. The docu has a few examples and is pretty clear on how to use them. [**Documentation**](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.validator.writing-validators.html)